# Android Text to Speech pitch like chipmunk voice

Tags: android, text-to-speech, chipmunk, pitch

Need help.

**How to make an Android TTS like chipmunk voice?**

I was set **pitch to 15**, but nothing much different with **pitch = 1**.

I'm using TTS with Indonesian local language and work great.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale("id","ID"));
        tts.setPitch(15);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void speakOut() {

    String text = mSpeak.toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
    } else {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is TTS engine that you choose exactly, but each of TTS engines have a range for properties - speed, volume, pitch, etc.

I think "15" is the over value about the range of pitch. So you will find min/max value of range, than set up the limit.

Answer (score -1):

I got result like yours. 
I changed the

```
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

to:

```
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

Finally it doesn't go like chipmunk voice again.